# Incorrect post request for nasdaq.com

Tags: python, python-requests

So I am trying to get 10 year historical data from Nasdaq. The default time period is 3 months and when changed it to 10 years and checked the page source the data/payload dictionary for the post request was "10y|false|FB"

**The data is publically available and can be downloaded as excel sheets.**

The response I collect with the post request is still 3 months instead of 10 years. Could anyone please tell me what is wrong here? Thank You!

```
url = "https://www.nasdaq.com"
s = requests.Session()
response = s.get(url)
Scookies = s.cookies.get_dict()

url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/FB/historical"

data = {'ddlTimeFrame':'10y',
        'onchange':'false',
         'symbol':'FB'}

data = json.dumps(data)

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N)  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Mobile Safari/537.36',
      'authority':'www.nasdaq.com',
        'method':'POST',
        'path':'/symbol/fb/historical',
        'scheme':'https',
        'accept':'*/*',
        'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'content-length':'12',
        'referer': url,
        'content-type':'application/json',
        'origin': 'https://www.nasdaq.com',
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

response = s.post(url, headers = headers , data = payload)
```

Comment: Are you confident that the data you're requesting should be available? It kind of looks like the data just doesn't go back that far.

Comment: Yes, this is the stock price for Facebook which although went public in 2012 should have data till 2012. I tried changing the data to '2y|false|FB' but it still doesn't go 2 years in the past.

Comment: The data may _exist_, but that doesn't mean the site will provide it. Are you confident that the site you're accessing, and the URL you're requesting, goes back that far?

Comment: Yes it's nasdaq.com. It allows users to download excel sheets with the data for free. I'm trying to avoid the manual process.

Comment: So this works if you do it manually? You should include that information in your question, and ask for help figuring out how that process differs from what your code does.

Comment: Tanay , I was inspecting Nasdaqs site I see they use javascript when you select 10 year data. So the question becomes based on the site setup does the java-script retrieve that data from an API, and if so whats the endpoint? Or is the data being rendered in the template then the java-script just displays it based on the selection?  Kinda need that information to continue further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to retrieve raw ten year data. I took a few screenshots. Mind you it comes rendered with the HTML template so you will need to strip that off, but I think I got you in the right direction.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRxHc.jpg

My Python Example:

```
import requests
```

`url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/fb/historical"`

`payload = "10y|false|FB"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }`

`response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)`

`print(response.text)`